# Using {fmt} to format containers

Tags: c++, c++17, fmt

I am trying to use {fmt} to print a std::vector or std::array like this:

```cpp
std::vector<double> vec = {1., 2., 3.};
fmt::print("{:0.3f}\n", fmt::join(vec, ","));
```

Thing is, I hope to print a transformed vector:

```cpp
std::vector<double> vec = {1., 2., 3.};
std::vector<double> vec_dup;
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(vec_dup), [](auto x){return x * M_PI;});
fmt::print("{:0.3f}\n", fmt::join(vec_dup, ","));
```

Is there a way to do this in C++17 without the need to create a new container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first see how in C++20 it can be easily achieved using the standard [`<ranges>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) library ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/33nKKasf3)):

```
    std::vector<double> vec = {1., 2., 3.};

    auto func = [](auto x){ return x * M_PI; };
    auto&& new_range = vec | std::views::transform(func);
    
    fmt::print("{:0.3f}\n", fmt::join(new_range, ","));
```

If you are limited to C++17 you have two options:

1. Use the 3rd party [ranges-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library implementing the same functionality. For it, just replace in the above code:

   ```
   #include <range>       --> <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
   std::views::transform  --> ranges::views::transform
   ```

   [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qojv79s88) demonstrating this.
2. Implement such a generator class yourself. The class should get the source range and generator function as parameters, implement `begin()` and `end()` functions returning a helper iterator class. The helper iterator class should keep iterator to the underlying range, and call the generator function on de-reference.

Comment: @auzn Is this helpful and gives you a satisfying solution?

Comment: It is indeed helpful. Thanks!. With {fmt} and ranges-v3, we are seriously thinking about simply switching to c++20...

Comment: @auzn Well, C++20 has many other advantages as well :-) Anyway, if this answers your question, please consider marking it as "accepted".